# Null pointer exception

Tags: java, pointers, exception, null

Here is my code The problem i'm having is an array out of bounds error.  Looking at the code I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is

// Name        :Kevin Randall
     // Username    :KRandall
     // Description :This program will create the dungeon and associated sounds

```
public class Dungeon
{
private  Cell[][] dungeon;
private Config config;
private int width;
private int height;
private Hero hero;
private Stats stats;
// Construct a new dungeon of the specified size.
// NOTE: The dungeon starts out completely empty and won't be usable 
// until other methods have been run the constructed object:
//  1) set() to initialize each Cell in the dungeons 2D array
//  2) addHero() to put a hero in the dungeon
//  3) addItem() to add keys and gems to the dungeon   
public Dungeon(Config config, int width, int height)
{
    this.config = config;
    this.width = width;
    this.height =height;
    dungeon = new Cell[width][height]; 
    stats = new Stats();
}

// Adds the specified hero to the dungeon
public void addHero(Hero hero)
{
    this.hero = hero;

}    

public int getHeight()
{
    return height;
}
public int getWidth ()
{
    return width;
}
public int getCount  ( Item item)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            dungeon[i][j].containsItem(item);
            if (dungeon[i][j].containsItem(item))
                count++;
        }

    }
    return count;
} 
public double getElapsedTime()
{
    return stats.elapsedTime();

}
// Setup a given grid location based on a string:
//  "W" = wall
//  "S" = secret passage
//  "D" = closed door
//  "O" = open door
//  "-" = dirt floor
public void set(int cellX, int cellY, String str)
{  
    String walls = config.wallImage();
    String pass = config.passageImage();
    String cDoor = config.closedDoorImage();
    String oDoor = config.openDoorImage();
    String floor = config.passageImage();
    String [] rock = config.rockImages();
    switch (str)
    {
    case "R": dungeon[cellX][cellY] = new CellRock(config);
    break;
    case "W": dungeon[cellX][cellY] = new Cell(walls);
    break;
    case "S": dungeon[cellX][cellY] = new CellPassage(pass);
    break;
    case "D": dungeon[cellX][cellY] = new CellDoor(oDoor,cDoor,true);
    break;
    case "O": dungeon[cellX][cellY] = new CellDoor(oDoor,cDoor,false);
    break;
    case "-": dungeon[cellX][cellY] = new CellPassage(floor);
    break;
    }
    hero.collectItem(dungeon[cellX][cellY].treasure);
    dungeon[cellX][cellY].treasure = Item.NONE;

}


// Add the specified item to a random location in the dungeon.
// The item can only be added to a cell that is passable (i.e.
// not a wall or a locked door). The location must not already
// have an item and items can't be added on top of the hero.     
public void addItem(Item item)
{   
    boolean placed = false;
    while(!placed){

        int xPos = (int)(Math.random()* width);
        int yPos = (int)(Math.random()* height);
        if (!(hero.getX() == xPos && hero.getY() == yPos)){
            if(dungeon[xPos][yPos].attemptToAdd(item)){
                placed = true;
            }

        }

    }

}

// Make the Hero execute the specified action.
// Currently this is attempting to move north, south, east, or west.
// If the hero succeeds in moving, play the walking sound.
// If the action would take the hero into an impassable cell OR 
// off the dungeon grid, play the hit wall sound.
public void execute(Action action)
{ 
    int x = hero.getX();
    int y = hero.getY();

    switch (action){
    case INVALID:
        break;
    case NORTH: y++;if (y < height && dungeon[x][y].attemptToMove(hero)){StdAudio.play(config.walkSound());hero.setLocation(x, y);}
    else StdAudio.play(config.hitWallSound());
    break;
    case SOUTH: y--;if (y >=0 &&dungeon[x][y].attemptToMove(hero)){StdAudio.play(config.walkSound());hero.setLocation(x, y);}
    else StdAudio.play(config.hitWallSound());
    break;
    case EAST:x++; if (x < width && dungeon[x][y].attemptToMove(hero)){StdAudio.play(config.walkSound());hero.setLocation(x, y);}
    else StdAudio.play(config.hitWallSound());
    break;
    case WEST:x--; if (x >= 0 && dungeon[x][y].attemptToMove(hero)){StdAudio.play(config.walkSound());hero.setLocation(x, y);}
    else StdAudio.play(config.hitWallSound());
    break;
    }

}

// Draw all the cell tiles that make up the dungeon.
// Also draws the hero.
public void draw()
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            dungeon[i][j].draw(config, i, j);
        }
    }
    hero.draw();

    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GREEN);
    StdDraw.text(64.0,64.0 * height - 32.0,"Keys:   " + hero.numKey);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
    StdDraw.text(192.0,64 * height - 32.0,"Gems:    " + hero.numGem);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
    StdDraw.text(320.0, 64 * height - 32.0,"Axe:    " + hero.numAxe);
}

// Test program for Dungeon, feel free to change for your own testing needs
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    // The config object stores defaults for sizes, sounds, and images
    Config config = new Config();

    // Setup a fake 4 x 3 dungeon
    final int WIDTH = 4;
    final int HEIGHT = 3;
    Dungeon dungeon = new Dungeon(config, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    StdDraw.setCanvasSize(WIDTH * config.cellPixels(), HEIGHT * config.cellPixels());
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, WIDTH * config.cellPixels());
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, HEIGHT * config.cellPixels());

    // Create a dungeon like:
    //  W--W
    //  W---
    //  WDW-
    dungeon.set(0, 0, "W");
    dungeon.set(1, 0, "D");
    dungeon.set(2, 0, "W");
    dungeon.set(3, 0, "-");

    dungeon.set(0, 1, "O");
    dungeon.set(1, 1, "-");
    dungeon.set(2, 1, "-");
    dungeon.set(3, 1, "-");

    dungeon.set(0, 2, "W");
    dungeon.set(1, 2, "-");
    dungeon.set(2, 2, "-");
    dungeon.set(3, 2, "W");


    Hero hero = new Hero(config, 1, 1);
    dungeon.addHero(hero);

    // Add 3 keys and 3 gems at random locations
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        dungeon.addItem(Item.KEY);
        dungeon.addItem(Item.GEM);
    }

    // Draw the sample dungeon
    dungeon.draw();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: You don't need to post the whole code. The problem is clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
dungeon = new Cell[width][height];
```

This create a two dimensionnal array of Cell objects, initialized with nulls. So every access is going to give you an exception. You need to create Cell objects and populate the array with them yourself.